# Cannot add a new project to an MVC application

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am teaching myself MVC and I am trying to learn how to do unit testing.  I wish to add a xUnit Test Project through my solution explorer but I do not see the option to add a new project.  I right click on the solution explorer, select add, and there are options to add new item, existing item, etc.. but no option to add a new project.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Typically there will be a solution node at the top of Solution Explorer. The project nodes will usually be beneath it. Is it possible you are right-clicking the project node instead of the solution node?

Comment: I was right-clicking the project node because solution node was not showing at the top.  I was able to fix this by pressing the forward button at the top of the solution explorer.  Thank you for your help.